# What is meaning of 'just throwing up to stuff more in'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, idioms

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Az5OgpcKrAU)

> They are just throwing up to stuff more in.
>   ([Here.](https://youtu.be/Az5OgpcKrAU?t=70))

Besides, there is

> And the library. All mahogany.
>   ([Here.](https://youtu.be/Az5OgpcKrAU?t=14))

Shouldn't it be *All is* ,or *All of*?

Comment: *All* is employed as an adverb = "entirely".

Comment: I can't see how the two parts should be posted together as a single ELL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. And the library. All mahogany.

This implies that the library is made of mahogany wood. "All of the library is made of mahogany". *And* is being used as a topic marker, so another way phrase it is

> Regarding the library, it is (all) made of mahogany.

---

> 2. They are just throwing up to stuff more in.

*Throw up* is idiom.

> [throw up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw%20up)
>   vomit

There is a issue with *stuff*.

> [stuff](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stuff)
>   2 a. To place forcefully into a container or space; thrust
>   4. To cram with food.

*More* is a pronoun that refers to *food*. So the the sentence means "They are vomiting to make room for more food." Or

> They are vomiting to make room so that they can force more food down their throats.

Also, it's probably a reference to [vomitoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vomitorium).
More info: [Vomitoriums: Fact or Fiction?](http://www.history.com/news/hungry-history/vomitoriums-fact-or-fiction).

Comment: 'All mahogany' is ungrammatical?

Comment: I can't really comment on grammaticallity.  Honestly, it's not even a complete sentence since it is missing a subject. So I would say yes, it is ungrammatical. However, they audience can still understand the meaning.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the sentence about throwing up is probably a reference to vomitoria. I included a link in my answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *vomitoria*, which (as is explained at your link) were entrance/exit passages in Roman theatres.

Comment: @StoneyB I guess I should have been clear, it is probably a reference to the _misconception_ about vomitoria.